# Call to a member function fill() on string on controler

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the ID of eloquent for editing its columns, but when I make the changes in the column in edit page and click done it returns this error. **Call to a member function fill() on string**

When I use the code `dd($id);` it returned the word 'update' on dd page.

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/books'], function($book){

    Route::get('edit/{id}','BookController@getUrlBook')->middleware('auth');

    Route::post('edit/{book}','EditController@update')->middleware('auth');

    Route::get('edit/{id}','BookController@getUrlBook', function ($book) {
        return view('edit',[
            'id' => $book->id,
            'name' => $book->name,
            'writer' => $book->writer_name,
            'isbn' => $book->isbn,
        ]);
    })->middleware('auth');

    Route::post('create','EditController@create');

    Route::get('create', function () {
        return view('create');
    })->middleware('auth');

});
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $imgExtensions = ['jpg','png','svg'];
        $id->fill($request->only(['name','writer_name','isbn']));
        if(null !== $request->book_image && in_array($request->file('book_image')->getClientOriginalExtension(), $imgExtensions )){
            $id->image = $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('images', $request->id.'.jpg');
        }
        $id->save();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly:

$id you got from method parameters is the book's id you want to update ...
so, you should use (fill) method for book model not its id ...

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $imgExtensions = ['jpg','png','svg'];
$book=Book::findOrFail($id);
        $book->fill($request->only(['name','writer_name','isbn']));
        if(null !== $request->book_image && in_array($request->file('book_image')->getClientOriginalExtension(), $imgExtensions )){
            $id->image = $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('images', $request->id.'.jpg');
        }
        $id->save();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

an other solution is using laravel binding:

```
Route::post('edit/{book}','EditController@update')->middleware('auth');

  public function update(Request $request,Book $book)  ....
```

now laravel will get $book from db for you, and you use the route the same way you were using it before

Comment: When I use model binding like you said it goes to this URL: admin/books/edit/update

Comment: And I get 404 error, as you can see it is supposed to go back to admin page

Comment: is this route allocated in route group? 
you will get 404 if this line faild:   $book=Book::findOrFail($id);

Comment: yes, update route is in a group. and I removed the "$book=Book::findOrFail($id);" line because model binding should get the $book, am I right xD

Comment: yes, if you used (Request $request,Book $book) model binding will get the book, and if you used (Request $request,$id) model binding will not

Comment: please share the whole group header (signature) of your route

Comment: I updated the routes on the question, please check it... And I used the model binding as you said, but when I click on 'done' on the edit page it redirects me to link that shouldn't redirect. And its only happening when I do model binding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219996/discussion-between-omr-and-libosch).